# openvp client "spoofing" server with IPv6

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, routing, openvpn

An openvpn client (windows 64 bit -presumable windows 8-) is connecting my OpenVPN server normally. After connecting, it is routing all it's vpn related traffic through the vpn, natting (seems to be doing that) it's IPv6 address via the IPv4.

The server shows in log:

> Thu Dec 17 15:34:39 2015 us=611122 user@company/xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:50135
>   MULTI: bad source address from client [fe80::8868:xxx:xxx:xxx], packet
>   dropped

All packets sent by the client are dropped like this, so VPN tunnel is established and kept alive but the client can't access any service

I don't have access to client terminal as it is in the other side of the world, nor I don't have too much experience in windows at all.

The client is generating the routing tables successfully, so is not permissions problem on it's side (is the only related information I found that could be causing the issue)

Windows client is OpenVPN 2.3.9
Server is Debian 8.2 with  Openvpn 2.3.4-5

Seems that the server shows the natted IPv6 as a spoofed address. And I don't know what can I change in windows side to nat better that address, nor in the server side as I didn't get this problem before and I'm not getting any look on google nor serverfault.

Comment: That is not a "natted" address; IPv6 doesn't have any such thing.

Comment: is not IPv6 is something under IPv4 that is allowing the packets to reach an IPv4 only server, I don't know how to call it in the right technical term. But thanks for the clarification. do you know what could it be?

Comment: seems that the client had problems generating the routes, it was reinstalled and working well now